# How to get total size of specific counted extensions

Tags: c#

I got the next code, written in c# which counts all extensions in directory and sub directory, now I can't get it to display the size of the counted extensions, I did try with FileInfo and other methods. but can't get it

I'm using Dictonary to store the extensions, count them, and display them

```
namespace ExtGet
{
    public class RecursiveFileProcessor
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nExtGet v0.2 BETA\n");
                Console.WriteLine("you should use the program with a path argument.\n");
                Console.WriteLine("eg: ExtGet.exe <path>\n");
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (string path in args)
                {
                    if (File.Exists(path) || Directory.Exists(path))
                    {
                        // this path is a file or directory
                        ProcessFiles(path);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{path} is not a valid file or directory.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static void ProcessFiles(string targetDirectory)
        {
            Dictionary<string, int> extensions = new();

            // count all extensions in directory and sub directory
            void CalcFilesCount(string targetDirectory)
            {
                IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, string>>? files = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory).GroupBy(p => Path.GetExtension(p));

                foreach (IGrouping<string, string>? ex in files)
                {
                    if (extensions.ContainsKey(ex.Key))
                    {
                        extensions[ex.Key] += ex.Count();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        extensions[ex.Key] = ex.Count();
                    }
                }

                foreach (string? p2 in Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory))
                {
                    CalcFilesCount(p2);
                }
            }

            CalcFilesCount(targetDirectory);

            // count all the files from directory and sub directory
            int fCount = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;

            // print out the results
            Console.WriteLine("\nExtGet v0.2 BETA\n");
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> items in extensions)
            {
                double percentage = (double)Math.Round((double)(items.Value * 100) / fCount, 2);

                if (items.Key == "")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"----------.unknown - {percentage}%");
                    Console.WriteLine($".unknown : {items.Value} files");
                    Console.WriteLine("------------------------------\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"----------{items.Key} - {percentage}%");
                    Console.WriteLine($"{items.Key} : {items.Value} files");
                    Console.WriteLine("------------------------------\n");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Total Files: " + fCount);
        }
    }
}
```

call the software with "extget.exe C:\FolderLocation"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Dictionary<string, int>`, there is only one `int` value .

What statistic values we want to gather are `Count` and `TotalSize`.

So I added a class `FileStatisticInfo` to store values as below, hope it helps:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

public class FileStatisticInfo
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public long TotalSize { get; set; }
}

public class RecursiveFileProcessor
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Use current working directory to test the code quickly.
        ProcessFiles("./");
    }

    public static void ProcessFiles(string targetDirectory)
    {
        Dictionary<string, FileStatisticInfo> extensions = new();

        // count all extensions in directory and sub directory
        void CalcFilesCount(string targetDirectory)
        {
            IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, string>>? files = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory).GroupBy(p => Path.GetExtension(p));

            foreach (IGrouping<string, string>? ex in files)
            {
                if (extensions.ContainsKey(ex.Key))
                {
                    extensions[ex.Key].Count += ex.Count();
                    extensions[ex.Key].TotalSize += ex.Sum(filePath => new FileInfo(filePath).Length);
                }
                else
                {
                    extensions[ex.Key] = new FileStatisticInfo
                    {
                        Count = ex.Count(),
                        TotalSize = ex.Sum(filePath => new FileInfo(filePath).Length)
                    };
                }
            }

            foreach (string? p2 in Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory))
            {
                CalcFilesCount(p2);
            }
        }

        CalcFilesCount(targetDirectory);

        // count all the files from directory and sub directory
        int fCount = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;

        // print out the results
        Console.WriteLine("\nExtGet v0.2 BETA\n");
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, FileStatisticInfo> items in extensions)
        {
            double percentage = (double)Math.Round((double)(items.Value.Count * 100) / fCount, 2);

            if (items.Key == "")
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"----------.unknown - {percentage}%");
                Console.WriteLine($".unknown : {items.Value.Count} files");
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------------\n");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"----------{items.Key} - {percentage}%");
                Console.WriteLine($"{items.Key} : {items.Value.Count} files, {items.Value.TotalSize} bytes");
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------------\n");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Total Files: " + fCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much I thought it was something from dictionary, thank you again